# EF-Migration: Side-affects of calling Down in Up?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

System:.NET Framework 4.7.2, Entity Framework 6 (not EF Core) on SQL Server. Code-first-approach.

This may sound odd, or funny, but it's a genuine question.
When I add an empty migration using "Add-migration" and then add SQL to create two or three views in "Up" and Drop them in "Down", will it have any side-affects if I call `Down()` as first Statement in `Up()` in order to remove any potentially manually created versions of these views on the target database - where it needs to be said that the Down Sql is fail-safe using `DROP IF EXISTS`?

Does the call to `Down` somehow magically invokes other EF routines for example affecting the versioning table `_MigrationHistory` or changes the way the migration is executed? Or is it just a simple procedure invoked like any other?

I thought it's just a simple routine and in order to have a proper clean-up before creating the database-objects the way I want them, it'll come in handy to just call the clean-up routine already available. But some of my colleagues disagreed, and said it's a no-no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

100% it's a "No-No".  Not because it will implicitly create some sort of recursion or failure-point, but because it will be a maintenance nightmare for whoever replaces you.

If your goal is to ensure that tables don't exist in the same way that the Down removes them, break that off into a function of it's own, that both Down and Up call explicitly.

```
private void RemoveIfExists(string tableName)
{
    //Remove tableName if it exists.
}

public void Up()
{
    RemoveIfExists("SomeTable");

    //Build 'SomeTable'.
}

public void Down()
{
    RemoveIfExists("SomeTable");
}
```

Comment: Hi @Perringaiden thanks for your reply. Especially the statement that it does not directly harm but is kind of bad practice, and can cause some kind of maintenance troubles. I agree, now. Also with a little edit I just need to use "CREATE OR REPLACE ..." to get rid of manually created stuff that might exist on the target db. Thx again.